# How can i get alternate data on odd/even basis inside action method using c# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want alternate data to save in database, as i have dynamic adding fields done with html input tag
below is my code in Controller, i am getting data in list parameter in form of array.
can anyone help me what will be logic i should put?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(DTab[] list)
    {

        foreach (DTab d in list)
        {

            //DTab[] dTabs = new DTab[];
            DTabViewModel dTabViewModel = new DTabViewModel();
            dTabViewModel.Name = d.Name;
            dTabViewModel.Email = d.Email;
            dTabViewModel.Number = d.Number;
            db.DTabs.Add(d);
            db.SaveChanges();


        }
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(DTab[] list)
    {
        int a = 1; //set value as 1 and then increment 
        foreach (DTab d in list)
        {
           
            //DTab[] dTabs = new DTab[];
            DTabViewModel dTabViewModel = new DTabViewModel();                      
            dTabViewModel.Name = d.Name;
            dTabViewModel.Email = d.Email;
            dTabViewModel.Number = d.Number;
            //n(n+1)
            if(a%2 == 0)  // for even number set this condition
            {
                db.DTabs.Add(d);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            a++; 
        
        }
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`if(a%2 == 0)` means that the loop is true `(i.e. should run the code inside it)`
when the value of n is a number that when divided by 2 has no remainder, i.e. any even number.

Same `if(a%2 == 1)` means any odd number